# How to properly setup a Virtual Network on Hyper-V (Windows 2008 R2) that provides external connectivity to guests

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, networking

I have a Hyper-V machine with one NIC card. I've set up a Virtual Network and provided connectivity to the guest OSs. The problem is that on restart of the host machine, i start up with no connectivity whatsoever (either for the host or the guests). I have to reconfigure the Virtual Network in the Hyper-V manager everytime to regain connectivity.

Am i doing something wrong? Is there a fix for this?

Comment: What sort of hardware are you running this on?

Answer (score 0):

I've had success in a dev/QA environment running Hyper-V with only a single NIC, but Microsoft recommends in a production environment that you use dual NICs (at least) with one of them dedicated to the host server.

[7 Best Practices for Physical Servers Hosting Hyper-V Roles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd744830.aspx)